# UIDocument with Autosave when is the file saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidocument

I setting up UIDocument to save my files to the device. I mark a file needs to be saved with

```
[ myDoc updateChangeCount:UIDocumentChangeDone ]
```

Now it appears that the saving operation only kicks in when one is leaves the app. Now what would happen if I dereference the file when I have the file open, thinking that I have its content saved already, would the autosave kick in before the file is dereferenced.

Thanks
Reza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're done with a UIDocument, you should close it using `UIDocument closeWithCompletionHandler:`